# Accessing response data from Angular promises

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a Rest call which returns response to the controller when everything is good and in case of exception , it has to return a default value.

```
$http.get(url).then(function(res){
    //do some convertion on the res.data if needed
    return res;
}).catch(function(error){
    //toast the error to the user
    return $q.when(/*default value */[]);
});
```

when i access this from a controller i face an issue.

```
MyService.getData().then(function(response){
       //assign the response to the controller variable
       vm.data = response.data;  //LINE XYZ
});
```

here at the line `XYZ` i am assigning the `response.data` value to the controller variable. The problem is, when there is an exception, the `$q.when()` returns a promise where the data is directly on the `response` instead of normal `response.data`.

Is there any way to return a proper `promise` which will be similar to the `$http`?

**Angular Version Used: 1.6.4**

Answer (score 0):

If you use the second argument of the `then` function, you'll get the response. Like this:

```
return $http.get(url).then(function(res){
    //do some convertion on the res.data if needed
    return res;
},function(res){
    //toast the error to the user
    return $q.when(/*default value */[]);
});
```

Is this what you're looking for? Otherwise, if you only need the data in your controller and not the complete response object, you could do this:

```
return $http.get(url).then(function(res){
    //do some convertion on the res.data if needed
    return res.data;
},function(res){
    //toast the error to the user
    return $q.when(/*default value */[]);
});
```

That way you wont run into the result of your `getData()` missing the `data`-property if an exception occurs.